# Doxygen command @file breaks generation of class description section

Tags: objective-c, doxygen

The command @file breaks the generation of the description section in the HTML doc generated by doxygen.

```
/**
 @file Class.h

 @brief Brief desc.

 Description text.
*/
```

In the output for Class.h no description section is generated. Thus the text "Brief desc" and "Description text" doesn't show up.

```
/**
 Class.h

 @brief Brief desc.

 Description text.
*/
```

Will generate the description section as expected.

As I want to document the global typdefs the @file command is necessary.

Is there any parameter in the config to force the generation of Description?

Answer (score 1):

Found the missing information.

By adding the @file commmand - as the documentation mentions http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdfile - the FILE is documented.

This means doxygen will create an extra document for that header file in the "Files" Tab and one in the usual "Classes" Tab.

Without the @file only that in "Classes" will be generated. In this case (without the @file) the initial comment and that above the Objective-Cs @interface will be interpreted as the combined description of the CLASS.

If the @file command is present, the initial comment will be used for the description of the file - which is located in the "Files" Tab.

The description of the class is only available if you provide a comment directly above the @interface line.